# Посоветуйте учебники по русскому языку для повторения школьного курса и углубления знаний?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография, обучение, образование

Здравствуйте. Пишу отчасти грамотно, но совершаю много ошибок. Если есть спорные моменты, то спрашиваю у поисковика.

Цели:

Мне стыдно, что я плохо знаю свой родной язык на должном уровне, поэтому этот пробел я хочу исправить.
Хочу быть грамотнее.
Поможет в профессиональной сфере(я полиграфист)

Спасибо.

Comment: Не знаю, насколько тут такие вопросы корректны. Слишком субъективно.

Comment: @behemothus, Что конкретно, выбор учебника?

Comment: Да. есть правило, что надо стараться избегать вопросов, допускающих множество "правильных" ответов... Не, я не буду голосовать за удаление, может кто и ответит, просто имейте в виду.

Comment: @behemothus, а где это правило написано? И что плохого в том, что много ответов будет правильных?

Comment: В "справке" посмотрите. Я сейчас другим занят, если не найдете, помогу.

Comment: @behemothus, я ознакомился, мой вопрос поподает под "конструктивный субъективный вопрос" 1. "подразумевают обмен опытом, а не мнениями;" - показать, как изучали другие. 2. "являются большим, чем просто бессмысленное веселое общение." - помочь человеку стать грамотнее и избавить его от стыда.

Comment: да не надо мне это все доказывать. Я не модератор. Просто все вопросы новичков проходят проверку опытными пользователями -  мне достался ваш. Я высказал свое мнение. А соревноваться в знании правил я с Вами не буду, тут хватает и реальных троллей.

Comment: Вот о чем речь, коли я уж Вам ссылку обещал. ***Не все вопросы хорошо вписываются в наш формат. Избегайте вопросов, которые сильно зависят от мнения отвечающего или тех, которые способны породить обсуждение вместо ответов.***  http://rus.stackexchange.com/tour. А Вы где свое нашли, если не секрет?

Comment: @behemothus, вот здесь http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, в конце. То есть, вы на мой вопрос не ответите?

Comment: Я не могу ответить, ибо это не моя стезя. Я не занимаюсь преподаванием. а если бы и занимался, т о меня отстанавливает вот эта строчка в тексте по вашей сслыке. ***[конструктивные субъективные вопросы]"подразумевают развернутые и подробные ответы"*** - как вы себе представляете развернутый и подробный ответ на ваш вопрос? Тут есть действующие и бывшие преподаватели, может они сочтут возможным что-то присоветовать.

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую:
- читать хорошие книги, классику. Газеты, журналы и интернет - не читать. И вообще, избегайте безграмотных текстов, а то потом привыкаеш и тоже хочецца так писать.
- можно читать блоги писателей и филологов.
- читать этот сайт и [грамоту](http://www.gramota.ru/).
- задавать вопросы на этом сайте. Местные пользователи будут соревноваться, кто быстрее и лучше ответит, чтобы поднять себе репутацию. Только не принимайте сразу первый же ответ, а подождите хотя бы сутки -- ответы улучшатся.

На учебники здесь я бы не очень рассчитывала, раз за школьные годы не помогло.

Comment: За школьные годы не помогло по другим причинам, хотелось бы осветить правила языка. А так да, вы правы, чтение книг помогает. Собственно благодаря им более менее и пишу.

Comment: Я думаю, что это более правильный подход. Идея найти - да еще по чужой наводке - в одном учебнике неконструктивна. тем более, что Розенталь тяжел для неподготовленных.

Answer (score 1):

Могу порекомендовать:

1. Русский язык: весь курс: для выпускников и абитуриентов - М.: Эксмо. 2010.  Розенталь. Д.Э., Голуб И.Б. Русский язык. Орфография, Пунктуация.

*Для скачивания:
[Rозенталь. Д.Э., Голуб И.Б. Русский язык. Орфография, Пунктуация.](http://www.school2-lgov.ru/images/DOCS/15291_-_Russky_yazyk_Orfografia_Punktuatsia.pdf)

2. Розенталь, Д. Э. И. Б. Голуб. Русский язык. Орфография, Пунктуация. - 3-е изд., испр. - Москва.: Айрис-пресс., 2002
   В сети этого учебника нет.
   *(14 издание - 2010 - b-s)*
3. Сайт [gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/)  раздел "Культура письменной речи".

Comment: Вообще-то Розенталь и Голуб - не совсем учебник. Скорее справочник. А ссылка ведет в никуда.

Comment: Вот есть ссылка на скачивание, не проверял, так что гарантировать не могу. http://mexalib.com/view/40378

Comment: Ну так дайте прямую ссылку на тот материал, на который ссылаетесь. А так это не намного лучше чем ссылка на гугл. Моя ссылка работает, проверил. Если это то же издание, о котором говорили вы, то повторяю, его в качестве учебника рекомендовать не могу. Простите, мне уже сделано замечание за флуд в комментариях, так что вынужден бессмысленную дискуссию прекратить. Просто ***прошу Вас впредь быть более конкретным в отношении ссылок***.

Comment: Я понимаю, что на сайт. Но не на "учебник", которого я там в полном виде не вижу. Поэтому прошу быть более конкретным. Надеюсь это понятно и правилам не противоречит. Все, спасибо, за внимание.

Comment: Я знаю сайт. И знаю что там много материала. Не надо мне объяснять. Просто дайте прямую ссылку на тот материал, на который ссылаетесь. Неужели это так трудно?

Comment: Серж, знаете что, я сейчас исправлю ваше сообщение, если все что Вы сейчас сказали - правда, то у Вас не должно быть возражений.

Comment: Да, поправил. Приношу извинения, но это фича движка, запятую вставляет в адрес.

Comment: Вот чего не пойму - что это за таинственное издание, "красного" цвета, у которого все данные совпадают с теми, что по моей ссылке, но все равно не оно? Может вот это? У неё издательство другое. "Айрис-пресс": http://book.nohoho.ru/product/russkiy-yazyk-orfografiya-punktuaciya-14-e-izdanie-pererabotannoe

Comment: Да, именно это. Только у меня третье издание. А у вас 14.

Comment: Да какое же может быть третье в 2010 г.??? Да еще "Эксимо"?

Comment: Розенталь, Д. Э. И. Б. Голуб. Русский язык. Орфография, Пунктуация. -  3-е изд., испр. - Москва.: Айрис-пресс., 2002. - 384 с.  - Домашний репетитор.

Comment: Ну значит, это не так книга, с которой начали? А с той что прикажете сделать? Удалить из рекомендуемых Вами?

Comment: Нет, это справочник.  Ладно, проехали.

Comment: [Розенталь, Голуб](http://www.school2-lgov.ru/images/DOCS/15291_-_Russky_yazyk_Orfografia_Punktuatsia.pdf)

Comment: Ну вставляйте в свой текст. Я уже устал.